# Issue with JPA @ManyToMany From A to B(NOT bidirectional) via C table, but the connection to B not by primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, spring-data

I have an JPA `@ManyToMany` issue

I have One Main entity called `Report`. I have several entities connect to `Report` with `ManyToMany` Relation. The connection is done via extra table. i.e with `@JoinTable` annotation. Each relation is `lazy`.

I have a function that fetch the `report` with all its relations. now, if i do fetch by accessing the property (i.e mark the function as `@Transcational` and access to each one of the property) everything works as expected. **But**, if I do

```
 CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<Report> query = cb.createQuery(Report.class);
 Root<Report> report = query.from(Report.class);

 ArrayList<Predicate> preds = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
 DomainSpecification.<Report>eager().toPredicate(report, query, cb);
 preds.add(DomainSpecification.<Report>idIsEqual(id).toPredicate(report, query, cb));
 query.where(cb.and(preds.toArray(new Predicate[preds.size()])));

 query.select(report);
 List<Report> results = em.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(1).get
```

I get all the relations as well but **One of the relation** (that has been connected to another table **NOT** by primary key) is fetching **alots** times. This means that the length of r.getProjects() is 13823 of the same value. i.e  of the same Project.

I'm attaching here the relevant source from `Domain Specification`/`Report.java`/`Project.java` and `Keyword.java` (the keyword is just to show an example for an entity that works good with this kind of fetching)
Maybe one can throw some light on this issues.

Thanks,
Oak

## Additional Information

### Code

`Report.java`

```
@Entity(name = "reports") public class Report implements Serializable, Auditing,JppDbObject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "REPORT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "report")
private ReportId report;
/*
 * this here for updating the reports_ids table.
 * 
 * set json ignore over this field.
 */

@Column(name = "txt", nullable = false)
private String txt;

@Column(name = "cleanTxt")
private String cleanTxt;

@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date creationDate;

@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED", nullable = false)
private Date lastModified;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
private Integer status;

@CreatedBy
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name="CREATOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private User createdBy;

@LastModifiedBy
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name="MODIFIER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private User modifiedBy;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="reportCommented")
//TODO make sure comments works good with lazy. @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="reportCommented")
private Set<ReportComment> comments;
 
/* this is the important line*/
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
      name="reports_projects",
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="report_id", referencedColumnName="REPORT_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="project", referencedColumnName="CODE")})
private List<Project> projects;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="reports_keywords",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="report_id", referencedColumnName="REPORT_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="keyword_id", referencedColumnName="keyword_id")})
private Set<Keyword> keywords;
```

`Project.java`

@Entity(name = "projects")
public class Project implements Serializable{

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false,unique = true)
private String code;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
private String description;

@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date creationDate;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.proj", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<ProjectPermission> permissions;
```

`Domain Specification`

public class DomainSpecification {

```
public static <T> Specification<T> eager() {

    return new Specification<T>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            for (PluralAttribute<? super T, ?, ?> fetch : root.getModel().getPluralAttributes()) {
                root.fetch(fetch, JoinType.LEFT);
            }
            query.distinct(true);
            return null;
        }

    };
}

public static <T> Specification<T> idIsEqual(final Long id) {

    return new Specification<T>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            
                        return cb.equal(root.get("id"),id);
        
        }

    };
}
```

}

### System

- Spring (4.0.6.RELEASE)
- Spring-Data (1.6.2.RELEASE)
- Hibernate EntityManager (4.3.6.Final - 4.2.1)
- MySQl Connector (5.1.13)
- cglib (3.1)
- aspectj (1.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue was connecting two table **not** via primary key. Although this can be done via normal sql. JPA produces unexpected result for me.